# 777 permission on Python script, but still get permission denied error from httpd log

Tags: unix

I have installed `/home/myname/python/Python-2.7.2/python` on my home dir.

But when I tried to called this script from my PHP:

```
$res = shell_exec("mypythonPath xxx.py");
```

It always gives out error: `/home/myname/python/Python-2.7.2/python denied`. I have 777 for the whole Python directory on my home dir. I also give 777 to this PHP file as well.

Very weird. Any clue?

Comment: You need to restart httpd after changing permissions for them to take effect.

Comment: Whatever else happens, don't leave the permissions on the file at 777 for an instant longer than necessary.  When you have a file with those permissions, you are saying you don't mind who modifies your program to do anything at all, such as delete all the files on the system that the person running the script has permission to delete.  And the permissions on the directly are only marginally less cataclysmic.  Yes, it may help with the debugging, but as soon as you've debugged, change the permissions (775 or 755 would be the basic change).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, 777 is only for debugging use

Comment: OK — that's fine (it comes under 'necessary').  Just remember to reset it back to a sensible value when you've resolved the problem.

Comment: You say "…/python denied"; that's not a normal error message.  Is that exactly what it says, or just an approximation?  Is the `mypythonPath` really the path name leading to Python, or is it a script of some sort?  Which directory is the process running this in?  Where is `xxx.py`?  Where is `mypythonPath`?  Have you checked permissions on every directory leading to Python?  Have you tried `strace` on `php` to see what's happening (a desperation measure)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Some programs even check for overly broad permissions and refuse to work with files set to 777. :-)

Comment: @melpomene I only know situation on refusing 777, which is the permission setting on the whole mounted drive. That is if the mounted drive is forbidden to run a script (+x), it will not allow execution even it is 777.